# Configuring FTP access for an IIS7 website

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, ftp

We are using the VStudio 2010 Publish command to keep our ASP.NET MVC 3 website synchronized. However we need FTP to facilitate the update of large setup binaries. Every tutorial I found on the internet ([like this one](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/305/configuring-ftp-75-user-isolation/)) talks about adding a new FTP site but I want to work on the same website already configured in IIS.

Is this really necessary?

I am only looking for a FTP account to be used with FileZilla FTP client to update our setup binaries in a website folder (*that eventually will be even faster then copying files via Remote Desktop Connection*).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an FTP binding to the existing site.

Like [this](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/303/adding-ftp-to-a-web-site/)!